# Является ли переменная $_GET числом без буквенных символов

Tags: php

Есть простой php-скрипт, в который переменной `$_GET` дается число > 0.
Мне нужно, чтобы при передаче в этой переменной, чего-либо кроме числа, скрипт завершал свою работу.

Если в скрипт передается значение не начинающееся с цифры, то он завершает работу. С этим я разобрался, но если передается что-то вроде `"666something"`, то он продолжает работу.

Подскажите, как решить эту проблему?

Comment: Какие именно числа будут передаваться? Целые? http://php.net/manual/ru/function.ctype-digit.php

Comment: Да, целые. Функция задачу решает, спасибо

Comment: Хм, при этом работают целые числа начинающиеся с нуля, например 0001 работает как 1. Есть ли возможность завершать работу при получении такого числа?

Comment: `^[1-9]\d*$` вам в помощь тогда

Answer (score 1):

На мой взгляд, самый оптимальный вариант - регулярное выражение:

```
$str = '777something';

if (!preg_match('~^[1-9]\d*$~', $str)) {
    die('Ошибка!');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php
       foreach ($_GET as $params)
        {
            if (ctype_digit($params))
            {
                //Если в GET будет только число, скрипт завершает работу
                exit;
            }
        }

 ?>
```

Comment: автор написал, что эта функция пропускает числа вида `000001`, то есть с ведущими нулями.

Comment: Простите, но 00001 это тоже число, насколько я знаю.

Answer (score -4):

Вот тебе функция пользуй потихоньку).

```
     function getNum($str){

    if($str!==(string)$str) {
        echo "Увы вы передали не строку((";
        return;
}
else{
     $var=$str{0};
       switch ($var){
       case '0';
       case '1';
       case '2';
       case '3';
       case '4';
       case '5';
       case '6';
       case '7';
       case '8';
       case '9';
           $result =  "Строка начинается с числа)";
           break;
           default;
           $result = "Начало со строки";
           break;
       } 

    return $result;
    }
 }

echo getNum('123fwefer');
```